# Invite to app on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

I want invite my friend to app on FB. My app is alive (so SandBox is allright), but I have this code:

HTML

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

JS

```
function inviteFriend() {
FB.init({
    appId: "**********", cookie: true,
    status: true, xfbml: true, 
});

FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: "Blaaa!",
    to: "***********"
},
  function(response) {
      if (response && response.post_id) {
          alert('Post was published.');
      }
      else {
          alert('Post was not published.');
      }
  });

}
```

And always, when I send request to my friend so I get alert "Post was not published.", but request was send and my friend see this invite card.

Comment: Why would the request dialog return a post_id …?

Comment: It is a good question. I forget that this script is older, and I didn´t updte my script. 
Problem was in post_id, tahnk you. :D